# How can I split elements by space and quotation within a list of list?

Tags: python

I have a list of data `df1`, that consists of three lists strings:

```py
df1 = [
    ['1 "P040" 68.13 "P040_1" 2.55 8'],
    ['2 "P040" 46.82 "P040_2" 2.53 8'],
    ['3 "P040" 46.82 "P040_3" 2.51 8']
]
```

I want to convert it to the following list of lists `df2`, without the double quotation marks (`"`):

```py
df2 = [
    ['1', 'P040', '68.13', 'P040_1', '2.55', '8'],
    ['2', 'P040', '46.82', 'P040_2', '2.53', '8'],
    ['3', 'P040', '46.82', 'P040_3', '2.51', '8']
]
```

I tried the following but does not work well

```py
for row in df1:
    for elem in row:
        elem.strip().split('"')
        elem.strip().split('"')
```

Comment: Try `result = [re.split(r'( |\'|\")', lst[0]) for lst in df1]`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple way to do this, you can replace unwanted quotes and then split by a space to get a list as result using a list comprehension:

```
df2 = [''.join(row).replace('"', '').split(" ") for row in df1]

print(df2)
```

Output:

```
[['1', 'P040', '68.13', 'P040_1', '2.55', '8'],
['2', 'P040', '46.82', 'P040_2', '2.53', '8'],
['3', 'P040', '46.82', 'P040_3', '2.51', '8']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since every list in the list consist of only one element, you don't really have to run through 2 `for` loops. This can be solved with an one-liner list comprehension:

```
df1 = [
['1 "P040" 68.13 "P040_1" 2.55 8'],
['2 "P040" 46.82 "P040_2" 2.53 8'],
['3 "P040" 46.82 "P040_3" 2.51 8']
]

df2 = [row[0].replace('"', '').split(' ') for row in df1]

print(df2)

>>> [['1', 'P040', '68.13', 'P040_1', '2.55', '8'],
     ['2', 'P040', '46.82', 'P040_2', '2.53', '8'],
     ['3', 'P040', '46.82', 'P040_3', '2.51', '8']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with nested list comprehension:

```
df2 = [[item.strip('""') for item in elem.split()] for row in df1 for elem in row]
```

Or nested loop with list comprehension:

```
df2 = []
for row in df1:
    for elem in row:
        df2.append([item.strip('""') for item in elem.split()])
```

Output:

```
['1', 'P040', '68.13', 'P040_1', '2.55', '8']
['2', 'P040', '46.82', 'P040_2', '2.53', '8']
['3', 'P040', '46.82', 'P040_3', '2.51', '8']
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a combination of the `split()` and `strip()` functions to split on both quotes and spaces.

This example will split the elements in `df1` and create a new `df2` list:

```py
df2 = []
for row in df1:
    new_row = []
    for elem in row[0].split('"'):
        new_row.extend(elem.strip().split())
    df2.append(new_row)

print(df2)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use shlex.split() to split on 'words', where a word might be a quoted string, as follows:

```
import shlex

for i in range(len(df1)):
    df1[i] = shlex.split(df1[i][0])
```

This is assuming that each of your list items is always one list containing the string.  This modifies df1 in place, to create a new 'df2', it would be:

```
import shlex

df2 = []
for row in df1:
    df2.append(shlex.split(df1[i][0]))
```

The output will be:

```
[
  ['1', 'P040', '68.13', 'P040_1', '2.55', '8'],
  ['2', 'P040', '46.82', 'P040_2', '2.53', '8'],
  ['3', 'P040', '46.82', 'P040_3', '2.51', '8']
]
```

The advantage of using shlex.split() is that the quoted strings can contain spaces without creating a problem that a plain 'split()' won't solve.

Comment: Just curious, but why is this voted down?  Just leaving it as '0' would be nice as it is a valid answer.  In my humble opinion that is... :)